# Lower bound for number of vertices in graph with certain forbidden minor

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected simple undirected graph and let $k>0$ be an integer such that

1. $\delta(G) \geq k$ (that is every vertex has at least $k$ neighbours), and
2. $K_{k+1}$ is not a minor of $G$.

**Question:** In terms of $k$, how many vertices does a graph satisfying 1. and 2. above to contain at least? In other words, I am looking for an interesting lower bound for $|V|$.

(Remark: a trivial lower bound for $|V|$ is $|V|\geq k+2$ as for $|V|=k+1$ we would get $G\cong K_{k+1}$ by point 1 above, violating point 2.)

Comment: Such a graph can be arbitrarily large, even for $k=4$.  For example, there are arbitrarily large planar graphs with minimum degree $4$.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. I am keen to know how many verices *at least* a graph satisfying 1. and 2. needs. Will edit question accordingly.

Comment: Well, in that case, $k+2$ is achievable.  For example, if $n \geq 6$ is even, then $K_n$ minus a perfect matching does not have a $K_{n-1}$-minor.

Comment: Oh - thanks! Do you want to put this in an answer so I can accept&close this, or should I better delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a graph with $k+2$ vertices for all $k \geq 4$.  To see this, first assume that $k$ is even.  Let $G$ be $K_{k+2}$ minus the edges of a perfect matching.  Note that every vertex of $G$ has degree $k$, but $G$ does not contain a $K_{k+1}$-minor.  For $k$ odd, just take the even example and add an apex vertex.

Comment: I had a similar problem posted somewhere before. Instead of $K_{k+1}$ as minor what if we seek number of vertices needed such that there is no genus $g$ graph minor?